# Do all Hogwarts students need to go to London in order to get to Hogwarts?

Tags: harry-potter

Someone on Reddit said something that made me curious about the answer. most analyses of Hogwarts place it somewhere deep in the mountainous areas of Scotland, based on excerpts from the books. Does that mean that a student from Leeds or even Newcastle would have to travel all the way down to London so they can get on the Hogwarts Express at 11 o'clock that takes them back all the way up through the parts of England they passed? Or are there more sensible methods for them to arrive at Hogwarts?

Comment: With Floo Network connections to Diagon Alley, the Knight Bus, and the possibility of Port Keys, I wouldn't think traveling to London would be a huge inconvenience (especially since they're likely to need to buy school supplies in Diagon Alley anyway).

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/e05Zm7s.jpg